# How to get current GMT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, gmt

I'm trying to get the current GMT/UTC regardless of the time zones my current database is located. The possible solution I found is:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE dbtimezone FROM DUAL;
```

and it is giving me the current GMT, but I am not 100% confident if this is the right way. Would anyone please help provide the best way to get the current GMT? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the current time in GMT, you'd want

```
SELECT systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'
  FROM dual
```

That will work regardless of the `dbtimezone`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your super quick answer, Justin! Yes, it worked and I feel more confident now...Thank you!

Comment: Thanks,how to insert above value using sql script in onle line ?